# Can't add a wpf user control to Visual Studio ToolBox

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am trying to create and add a wpf user control to my Visual Studio Toolbox. If I create the control in WPF (.NET Framework) everything works fine. But if I create my control using .NET 8, I get an error when I try to add the control.

These are the steps I follow: right click on toolbox controls and click on choose items. Then I click on WPF Componentes and I get this error: "Tab population failed because an exception occurred: Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other instances. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131401).

Any help understanding this, please? Why does it work when I create a .net framework component and not for WPF components?

[image]